# Select Node with size of Its specific child Node In Linq, HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, linq, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get following data.

```
<html>
<body>
<tr class="udline">
    <th rowspan="2" class="noln">시간</th>
    <th rowspan="2">개인</th>
    <th rowspan="2">외국인</th>
    <th rowspan="2">기관계</th>
    <th colspan="6" class="eb">기관</th>
    <th rowspan="2">기타법인</th>
</tr>
<tr class="udline">
    <th class="sub">금융투자</th>
    <th class="sub">보험</th>
    <th class="sub">투신<br>(사모)</th>
    <th class="sub">은행</th>
    <th class="sub">기타금융기관</th>
    <th class="sub">연기금등</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="11" class="blank_07"></td>
</tr>
<!-- following are data -->
<tr>
    <td class="date2">18:01</td>
    <td class="rate_up3">2,024</td>
    <td class="rate_down3">-3,307</td>
    <td class="rate_up3">1,116</td>
    <td class="rate_up3">824</td>
    <td class="rate_down3">-16</td>
    <td class="rate_up3">764</td>
    <td class="rate_down3">-43</td>
    <td class="rate_down3">-5</td>
    <td class="rate_down3">-408</td>
    <td class="rate_up3">166</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="date2">18:00</td>
    <td class="rate_up3">2,022</td>
    <td class="rate_down3">-3,305</td>
    <td class="rate_up3">1,116</td>
    <td class="rate_up3">824</td>
    <td class="rate_down3">-16</td>
    <td class="rate_up3">764</td>
    <td class="rate_down3">-43</td>
    <td class="rate_down3">-5</td>
    <td class="rate_down3">-408</td>
    <td class="rate_up3">166</td>
</tr>
...
</body></html>
```

I want to get Nodes list of "tr" tag which has a data. but I have problem with getting "tr" tag.
I think it is enough if I can get sets of "tr" which has 11 td tags.
so I write following source.

```
result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri(timeUrlAddress));
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(result);
var nodes = 
    htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr")
    .Where(i => i.ChildNodes.Any(j => j.Name.Equals("td")).Count>10); // <--- I have Problem.

foreach(var i in nodes) {  ... } // <-- iterating list of <tr> tags.
```

and It doesn't work.
I could get List of tr tag with **DoucmentNode.SelectNodes("//tr")** ... and I appended **.Where(i=>i.ChildNodes.Count >10 )** to get what i want.
but tr has several "text"childNodes and I get Unwanted Node. following picture shows that I got with .Where(i=>i.ChildNodes.Count>10).

[image]

I want to get tr node that has td tag as child nodes and has exactly 11 of td tag.
how can I get that tr nodes with Linq syntax..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `tr` node with exactrly 11 `td` children you can use below XPath:

```
//tr[count(td) = 11]
```

Comment: Thank you, I solved with that Xpath syntax.  **var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[count(td)=11]");**.